# How to display the latest 3 items in django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to query django model to display the latest 3 items in a section of my template and display the next 3 on the next part of my template in order?
for example: some_list is ['a', 'b', 'c','d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], so [:3] gives you ['a','b','c'] so how do i get the next 3 from 'd' to 'f' in my query?

Comment: Can you be more clear ? what do you mean by the next 3 on the next part of my template in order ?

Comment: Have you tried the slicing tag? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

Comment: @tr0yspradling yes i tried slicing but the problem for instance [:3] If some_list is ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e', 'f', 'g'], the output will be ['a', 'b','c'], so how do i slice from e to g

Comment: @Barrow Would this work? `x[len(x)-3:]`

Comment: @tr0yspradling please how do i put that in a query form in django. eg. post = Post.objects.order_by('-created')[:3]

Comment: I would do something like:
`return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form': form, 'my_list': my_list})`

Then in your template: `{{ my_list[len(my_list)-3:] }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If you're passing in an `object_list` in the context data, you can do something like this.

```
{% for o in object_list|slice:":3" %}
    {{ o }}<br>
{% endfor %}

<section>
Miscellaneous HTML Stuff
</section>

{% for o in object_list|slice:"3:6" %}
    {{ o }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

If you don't have `object_list` in your context, then you can either add it or create two separate context variables with the data you are looking for.

```
class MyView(ListView):
    model = MyModel

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['list1'] = MyModel.objects.all()[:3]
        context['list2'] = MyModel.objects.all()[3:6]
        return context
```

And your template would loop through `list1` and `list2` instead of `object_list`.